# retrieve content of a function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I created a function in oracle, which returns one single record, as follow :

```
create or replace function exportFile_TC return COMPENSE_TC_TABLE AS 
     retval COMPENSE_TC_TABLE := COMPENSE_TC_TABLE();
begin
   retval.extend;
   retval(retval.count) := COMPENSE_TC('A', 0, '788', '000000002582055', '0778153', '10209077105333978893', '08025011091000160486', 'TRANS TRAVEL', 'HTL EDEN', 1, null, null, '00000000000000000155', null, '00000000', '20150209', '08', null, null, null);
   return(retval);
end exportFile_TC;
```

Now when I do a query :

```
select exportFile_TC from dual;
```

all i get is :

```
EXPORTFILE_TC
-------------
<Object>
```

what I need is how to be able to retreive the content of the return value of my function. ?
it is my first time using oracle functions, so may be I missed sthing.

Comment: The function can be simplified to: `create or replace function exportFile_TC return COMPENSE_TC_TABLE AS begin return COMPENSE_TC_TABLE( COMPENSE_TC('A', 0, '788', '000000002582055', '0778153', '10209077105333978893', '08025011091000160486', 'TRANS TRAVEL', 'HTL EDEN', 1, null, null, '00000000000000000155', null, '00000000', '20150209', '08', null, null, null) ); end exportFile_TC;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [a table collection expression](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#i2065746):

> The *table_collection_expression* lets you inform Oracle that the value of *collection_expression* should be treated as a table for purposes of query and DML operations. The *collection_expression* can be a subquery, a column, a function, or a collection constructor. Regardless of its form, it must return a collection value—that is, a value whose type is nested table or varray. This process of extracting the elements of a collection is called collection unnesting.

So in your case as your function is returning a nested table type you can do:

```
select * from table(exportFile_TC);
```

Each field in your object type will be shown as a column in the result set.